# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(f)$ is a principal ideal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $
> f(t)=t^{4}-2 t^{3}+2 t^{2}-2 t+1 $, prove that $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(f)$ is a principal ideal ring.

We know that $f(t)$ is the product of two irreducibles:

$$t^{4}-2 t^{3}+2 t^{2}-2 t+1 = (t^2+1)(t^2-2t+1)$$

Hence $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(f)$ is not a field (since $f(t)$ isn't irreducible, it is not maximal in the PIR $\mathbb{Q}[t]$).

How can I conclude that $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(f)$ is not a principal ideal ring?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: is $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ a principal ideal ring? How do ideals of this ring and the ring in question relate?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ is a principal ideal ring because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. The ideals of  $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(f)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ that contains $(f)$, the non trivial ideals that contains $(f)$ are $\left(t^{2}+1\right)$ and $\left(t^{2}-2 t+1\right)$. 

Hence, the non trivial ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(f)$ are $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(t^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[t] /(t^2-2t+1)$. Those ideals are principal since those two polynomials are irreducible in the principal ideal ring $\mathbb{Q}[t]$. What do you think?

Comment: That sounds good, but I think you need to argue that you've found all the ideals containing $f$. Alternatively, if you consider the map $R \to R/I$ for a general ring $R$ and ideal $I$, what happens to the principal ideals of $R$?